# Is it ok to just say 'Sem'?

Tags: ortografia

So I'm working on some app development and using Portuguese as a target language. I have a section of the app that allows the user to change some settings. One of the settings is a timer. Previously I have had it say 'Sem relógio'. But for cutting down on space, I want to just have it say 'Sem'. Is this acceptable in Portuguese and does it make sense to native speakers?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115567/discussion-on-question-by-pianoman102-is-it-ok-to-just-say-sem).

Answer (score 4):

This is to make the layout clear:

**MANTEIGA** [BUTTER]

- Sem [without]
- Com [with]

BETTER:

**MANTEIGA**

- Sim
- Não

Unless the subject matter is on the screen, just using sem makes zero sense. In any case, you are better off with Yes/No.

Even in English, we would not say:
Timer

- With
- Without

We'd use TIMER, YES or NO, for example.